# Prove that there exists a right ideal $K \in R$ such that $I \cap K = \{0\}$ and $I + K = J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ and $J$ be right ideals in a ring $R$ with identity such that $I \subset J$ and $\frac JI \cong R$ as right R-module. Prove that there exists a right ideal $K \in R$ such that $I \cap K = \{0\}$
and $I + K = J$.

Comment: it seems that $K=\frac{J}{I}$. Just need to prove that it is indeed right ideal.

Comment: @jane that's an ideal in R/I but the question aims for an ideal of R

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$0\to I\to J \to J/I\to 0$ is a split exact sequence since, by your hypothesis, $J/I$ is projective.